# Access variable in main thread from second thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boolean, thread-safety

I have a function (messageArrived) that call's a function (setAnimation) inside a new thread. How can i access a boolean that is defined inside the messageArrived function and access it in the second thread?

If there is a new message i want to terminate the second thread (setAnimation). I fugured that whit a boolean is the only way to "terminate" a thread.

```
#include <thread>

bool start = false;

void setAnimation(std::string msg){
    start = true;
    while(start){
       //do something
    }
    return;
}    

int messageArrived(std::string message){
     start = false;
     std::thread t1(setAnimation, message);
     t1.detach();
     return 1;
}
```

Above code is just an example to clarify my question.

Comment: Like with any other function, you need to pass it by pointer/reference to the function.

Comment: Local variables are local to the scope they were defined in. Threads doesn't change that.

Comment: There's little point to that, as `start` ceases to exist when `messageArrived` returns and so there's nothing for you to access.

Comment: @Janoshh You already have what you want. Just make that bool `std::atomic<bool>` to avoid race conditions. I have to say that this is a catastrophe in design, but it should work.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Allright! Do you have a suggestion for better disign?

Comment: Use `std::promise` and `std::future` with an event loop that checks what you want to check. It looks like: `while (theFuture.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10)) != std::future_status::ready) {//do stuff}`. The resaon this is bad design is because you have global variables. Wrap everything in classes correctly.

Comment: `bool start = false;` should be `std::atomic<bool> start{false};`.

Comment: Do you want something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c14324823815c86) ?

Comment: @Jarod42: +1, Yes! that did the job, I tweaked it a little like detach the thread etc. How can I upvote your comment?

Answer (score 1):

When creating your thread, you can pass a variable by reference using `std::ref` However, you would still need to have your variable outside the function, else it will get out of scope.

```
std::thread t1(setAnimation, message, std::ref(myVariable));
```

Comment: if the boolean is set to false in the main, wil the whileloop in the second thread notice that change?

Comment: That will lead the thread to have a reference to a variable that goes out of scope, and the OP will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Janoshh it's a reference to the bool value, so yes the change will be 'visible' inside the thread.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I'm new to programming in C++. If i understand your answer, by passing the boolean with std::ref, the thread is gonna terminate but it is not a save way to do it?

Comment: cppreference have a [good exemple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) of the use of `std::ref`.

Comment: @Janoshh Maybe, or maybe not. When you have undefined behavior (like using a reference to something that doesn't exist) then the behavior is really *undefined*. Having undefined behavior (abbreviated to UB) means the whole program is *ill-formed* and invalid, and nothing it does can be trusted.

Comment: This solution is WRONG. That `start` is global! Why would you wanna pass stuff by reference here?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I like to provide alternatives of just 'putting everything global'.
Indeed, if Janoshh decides to use a global variable, it might not be relevant to pass it by reference (yet it is perfectly valid), but if he wants his thread to be managed by an object, it might become relevant.